# How to ensure analytics data is from the server it claims it is from?

Tags: javascript, authentication, http-headers, analytics

I have an analytics script (javascript) which is added to a website via a `script` tag in `/html/head`.

The analytics script tracks some of the user's actions, saves it in JSON format, and sends the JSON to a server for analysis. The analytics server uses the JSON to determine which website sent the data (e.g. there's a referer value in the JSON).

I am concerned someone could fake this data.

For example, if someone wanted to interfere with a website's analytics, they could send fake JSON data to the analytics server. Perhaps they would fake the referer value in the JSON, and would also fake the HTTP header so it looks like it's coming from the target website.

Is there a way to prove (with high probability) that data sent from website1 really is from website1?

Comment: Does the client running the JS send it back to the website (which relays to you), or directly to your servers? In the latter case I suspect the answer is no (because you've only got data from a browser which can easily be manipulated).

Comment: The client running the JS sends it directly to my servers. The website doesn't interact with the data at all.

Comment: Would DNS look up of the supposed website + IP log help? I guess for more complicated set up with CDN or load balancing servers it might(?) get tricky? (sorry I am no network admin and I am not sure if it is relevant at all)